# Create a share on iscsi drive in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share, iscsi, server-message-block, share

I am brand new to server administration but I don't belive im trying to do anything to exotic

I have a windows server 2012 (standard)
and a drobo 800i

My goal is to setup company shares on the iscsi target I have setup on the drobo

So far I have:

- initialized the iscsi and connected
- made the iscsi disk read/write(it default started as read only)
- formatted and mounted it (as drive   E:)

from the server local desktop I can see and write files to the E:\ drive

- in shares wizard I do not see it as a volume option
- when I view the volumes window I see (e: drobo Fixed 16tb 16tb)

I'm new to everything but I would think since its a mounted drive I should be able to share a folder on it but it appears its not that straight forward

suggestions?

Comment: We are using a Drobo with Windows Server 2012 just as you described. Normal windows sharing was setup and it is working fine. A word of caution about using Drobo and iSCSI, DO NOT ENCRYPT the iSCSI volume. It will render it unusable by the Drobo. It is published that it will not work, but a few of us thought we'd try it anyways..

Comment: Well, I guess I can try again.  My answer was meant to indicate that it does in fact work as a normal drive and Windows sharing should work like any other drive.  if you create a folder, r-click, properties, does the sharing tab not show up?  Can you share folders from the drive the OS is sitting on?

Comment: I was trying to be a good boy and use the server manager software to set the drive up. I will check shortly and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loss of your Drobo's shared resource settings (i.e., the volumes do not show) can be caused when the server service in Windows starts up before the iSCSI Initiator service does. The server service needs the iSCSI service to have already started file shares.

For Windows 2008:

1. Go to Control Panel.
2. Open "ISCSi Initiator."
3. Go to Volumes and Devices (performs the "bind volume" operation).
4. Click on Auto Configure. 5. Assuming the Drobo is mounted (boxes checked in Dashboard), the window (Auto Configure) should populate with drive letters, mapped to the Drobo device.

See more at: http://support.drobo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/309#sthash.eppD4y9h.dpuf